# python ctypes windowserror exception access violation reading

Tags: python, ctypes, access-violation

```
from ctypes import *;
import os;
import sys;

def callAppPlugin(url):
    pid = os.getpid();
    h=WinDLL('somes.dll')
    nRst = h.register("18132163","lgsg");
    nRst1 = h.init(pid);
    nRst2 = h.parse_site(url);
    str = string_at(nRst2);
    return str;
```

I use python 2.7 to call a dll(some.dll), and do some functions in the dll,like register, init...

The py file run on my computer(win10) is OK.But cannot run on my server(win server 2008), when the process do the init function, it throws exception:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFF8
```

why? help~